# What does it mean when I'm glowing red in a fight?

Tags: fate-samurai-remnant

What does it mean when I'm glowing red in a fight?

[image: glowing red]

It doesn't happen all the time and I'm currently using earth stance in the screenshot. It looks similar to **Afterglow** but it's not that and I haven't cast any spells. I'm not too low on health or have any other bars filled usually. I don't recall a tutorial popping up about this. Perhaps it's a passive skill that I unlocked? None of the earth stance skills I have seems to indicate any passive traits other than **Perseverance** or **Expansive Fortitude**.

[image: skill tree]

- **Perseverance** - Attacks in Earth Stance will no longer be repelled by enemies.
- **Expansive Fortitude** - Increases max Fortitude while in Earth Stance.

It appears to be a buff of some kind, but I don't know what is being buffed or what the source is. Came across a fight where all the enemies were glowing red.

[image: they're glowing now]

Comment: I looked at some playback of this fight and I stopped glowing the moment I opened up the Affinity Technique menu but did nothing and closed.